# Two-way ANOVA results change after doing some calculations on the data?

Tags: anova, two-way

I grow cells, and I measured the diameter of a bunch of cells on different days and under different treatments. And then I use the diameter data to calculate the biovolume of the cells (assuming they are just spheres).

So basically I have a bunch of cell diameter data and biovolume data calculated from the cell diameter data. The biovolume data is the meaningful data that needs to go in a manuscript I'm writing.

I noticed that when I do Two-way ANOVA on the biovolume data, there is no sig. diff. between Treatments (p = 0.13), but if I do the same stats on the cell diameter instead, there is sig. diff between the treatments (p = 0.0074).

I'm kind of surprised by the difference between using the 2 datasets, because all biovolume is calculated from the diameter using the same equation, so I thought all the variances would stay relatively the same and wouldn't affect the stats result...

So my gut tells me that I should be using the cell diameter as "proof" for whether there is a size difference between the cells, since that would be the least manipulated data, but like I said, the biovolume would be the number that people care more about, so it might be weird that I report biovolume numbers, but use cell diameter for stats to say whether they are the same size....

Here's what my data looks like in R, and I just used `aov()` to do the two-way ANOVA

```
dat <- structure(list(Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Day 0", "Day 1.2", "Day 2", 
"Day 7", "Day2.3"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("D", 
"E", "S"), class = "factor"), Cell.Diameter = c(5.687978, 5.545658, 
5.850898, 5.687978, 5.545658, 5.850898, 6.52893, 6.765911, 6.451542, 
6.433454, 6.416563, 6.283359, 5.747511, 6.132264, 6.328667, 4.974635, 
4.47831, 4.836779, 6.511466, 7.626786, 7.626786, 6.156435, 6.150705, 
5.881272, 5.611669, 6.219433, 5.527563, 4.007459, 4.34317, 3.938299, 
5.442596, 6.147537, 6.120605, 7.081396, 6.86932, 6.874861, 6.329233, 
5.965546, 6.07726, 5.796541, 6.493651, 6.113787, 5.354956, 5.553488, 
5.706231), BioVol = c(96.35457, 89.30131, 104.8736, 96.35457, 
89.30131, 104.8736, 145.72185, 162.1726, 140.60123, 139.42196, 
138.32671, 129.88958, 99.41185, 120.74277, 132.71971, 64.45882, 
47.02634, 59.24713, 144.55558, 232.28616, 232.28616, 122.17618, 
121.83535, 106.51539, 92.52834, 125.96533, 88.43001, 33.69814, 
42.89623, 31.98339, 84.41449, 121.64718, 120.05538, 185.93246, 
169.72269, 170.1337, 132.7553, 111.16017, 117.52277, 101.97773, 
143.37237, 119.65464, 80.40189, 89.6801, 97.28516)), .Names = c("Day", 
"Treatment", "Cell.Diameter", "BioVol"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-45L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your `BioVol`, I am assuming you applied some sort of a cube function to your `Cell.Diameter` data. Transforming your data will certainly change the shape of your data distribution. That's why data transformations are also done when the assumptions for conducting ANOVA are not met (e.g. normality and equality of variances). **In your case, applying your `BioVol` function resulted in an increase of spread in your data. This can be seen in the F-value (or signal to noise ratio). For `Treatment` your F-value got smaller resulting in more "noise" and a non-significant result.**

Here are your ANOVAs (assuming your data is called `dat`):

```
m1<-aov(Cell.Diameter~Day*Treatment,data=dat)
summary(m1)

              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Day            4  33.47   8.367  65.352 2.24e-14 ***
Treatment      2   1.49   0.743   5.806 0.007387 ** 
Day:Treatment  8   5.21   0.651   5.083 0.000469 ***
Residuals     30   3.84   0.128                     

m2<-aov(BioVol~Day*Treatment,data=dat)
summary(m2)

               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Day            4  62534   15634  47.866 1.33e-12 ***
Treatment      2   1405     702   2.150  0.13404    
Day:Treatment  8   8686    1086   3.324  0.00771 ** 
Residuals     30   9798     327
```

Now by looking at the boxplots you can see that the distributions between the two plots are not identical. On another note, I would also explore your data a bit more to see whether you are not violating the equality of variance assumption in ANOVA.

```
boxplot(resid(m1)~Day+Treatment,data=dat, main="Cell Diameter")
boxplot(resid(m2)~Day+Treatment,data=dat, main="Cell Volume")
```

**Here's a visual check to see how your data transformation from `Cell.Diameter` to `BioVol` resulted in an increased variation in the data leading to the non- significant `Treatment` effect (error bars represent standard error):**

```
require(plyr)
dat2 <- ddply(dat,.(Treatment), summarize, DIAM=mean(Cell.Diameter),
          ERROR.DIAM=sd(Cell.Diameter)/sqrt(length(Cell.Diameter)),
          VOL=mean(BioVol),
          ERROR.VOL=sd(BioVol)/sqrt(length(BioVol)))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat2, aes(x=Treatment, y=DIAM))+
geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=DIAM-ERROR.DIAM,ymax=DIAM+ERROR.DIAM),size=1)+
ggtitle("Cell Diameter")

ggplot(dat2, aes(x=Treatment, y=VOL))+
geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=VOL-ERROR.VOL,ymax=VOL+ERROR.VOL),size=1)+
ggtitle("Cell Volume")
```

**Regarding your question whether to use `Cell.Diameter` vs. `BioVol` to calculate your stats, I would suggest using `BioVol` since that is the measure that people mostly use in your field. However, you might want to point out in the discussion that `Treatment` had a significant effect when `Cell.Diameter` was considered. In any case, you should also note that your *interaction term* is significant in both cases, which perhaps is the more important information to look at:**

```
# CHECK ORDER OF FACTOR LEVELS
dat$Day

# CHANGE THE ORDER OF FACTOR LEVELS SEE ALSO ?factor
dat$Day_ordered<-factor(dat$Day, levels=c("Day 0", "Day 1.2", "Day 2", "Day2.3", "Day 7"))

# Cell.Diameter
with(dat,interaction.plot(Day_ordered, Treatment, Cell.Diameter))

# BioVol
with(dat,interaction.plot(Day_ordered, Treatment, BioVol))
```

Comment: Although you seem to be focusing on the crucial elements of the situation, it is still not clear what your answer is.  What specific recommendations do you have for the OP concerning how to compare these groups and reconcile the apparently contradictory p-values?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for pointing this out. I addressed your comment (highlighted my changes in **bold**). I don't understand though what you meant by "_apparently contradictory_ p-values"?

Comment: The difference  between 0.13 and 0.0074 is profound, because in most circumstances the former would not be considered significant and the latter would.  Your observation about the interaction term is interesting and useful.  I would like to suggest, though, that it could be at least as useful to pay more attention to the *shapes* of the distributions of the residuals: that ought to play an important role in deciding how best to express the results.

Comment: Yes, regarding the p-values I agree. However, I read "apparently" more as "seemingly", i.e. the p-values seem to be different but are not really (for some reason which wasn't clear to me). Your comment cleared this up. I will give your last suggestion a bit more thought as I am not 100% what are you hinting to. Again, I appreciate your input as it also helps me to learn!

Comment: @Stefan Thank you so much for your answer. I know that it's important to test for interactions in these situations, but I'm not quite sure what it means biologically... Does it mean that the way the cell sizes change over the 7 day period are different among the treatments? I read that if you get interaction, you should focus on the multiple comparison post test instead, so do I use Tukey in this case to look at treatment difference? Thank you again!

Comment: @Fenrir No problem! If that answer helped you, you could also consider accepting it. Regarding interactions, it is always good to plot them. I edited my post above for you to see how you can quickly visualize those interactions. I will leave it up to you to interpret your interactions. Yes, you can, for example, run the `TukeyHSD()` command on your `aov()` objects `m1` and `m2`.